# Probability of a Discrete Time Markov Chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

I am given a transition matrix with state space $s=(1, 2, 3)$. I want to find the $P(X_4 = 2 | X_6 = 2)$. The transition matrix is:
\begin{pmatrix}
0.4 & 0.2 & 0.4\\
0.5 & 0 & 0.5\\
0.5 & 0.5 & 0
\end{pmatrix}

I understand for example if it was $P(X_6 = 2 | X_4 = 2)$ that I would use $P^2(2,2)$ but I am not sure what to do when the given X is a few steps further than the one we want to find.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe use Bayes' theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).

Comment: @Sierra The question doesn't make sense unless we have some more information. If we know (or have a distribution over) the initial state of the Markov chain, then we could move forward by using Bayes' theorem:
$$
P(X_4 = 2 \mid X_6 = 2) = \frac{P(X_6 = 2\mid X_4 = 2) P(X_4 = 2) }{P(X_6 = 2 )}.
$$
Note in particular that there is no answer to the probability $P(X_k = 2)$ given only the nature of the Markov chain.